# why some curves does not work properly

Tags: animation, particles, physics, force-fields, curve-modifier

I am trying to make the particles follow a curve.
I make a curve, add a force field to it, set it to a curve guide, and let it run
This works great for most curves but for some reason not for others, and the particles float a little around the curve.
like shown in the picture:
[image]

does anyone know why this happening?

Comment: could you provide your blend file so we can see your settings? thx

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=ymd3VM5s" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/ymd3VM5s/) HERE IS THE LINK TO MY FILE. THANK YOU!